# Visual Studio Black Screen at running

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I made a new wpf project, there are not errors or something, but when i run it the screen is just black, i also reinstalled Visual Studio but no effect, please help.

This is how it looks like when it is running :

[image]

But in the designer it looks normal.

Much Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to show your code for us to understand the situation. Did you try debugging? Do you have UI controls on the window? Any external API?

Comment: You could press the buttons at the top of the window that allow you to inspect the Visual Tree. That might give a clue. (Or the graphics card/driver is messing up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Thanks to Erno de Weerd from the comments, with his solution i saw that the "Override Default Style" - Option was activated, which gave me this black screen...